# Dart unit tests fail to run on Github Actions

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I have a dart project with unit tests. When I run the unit tests locally they run successfully.

I added CI to the project with Github Actions. The same unit tests that run successfully locally, fail on Github Actions with the following error:

```
00:00 +0: loading test/foo_test.dart
00:01 +0: loading test/foo_test.dart
00:01 +0 -1: loading test/foo_test.dart [E]
  Failed to load "test/foo_test.dart":
  Couldn't resolve the package 'foo' in 'package:foo/foo.dart'.
  test/foo_test.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'package:foo/foo.dart'
  import 'package:foo/foo.dart';
         ^
  test/foo_test.dart:33:26: Error: Method not found: 'Bar'.
      final bar = Bar(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^

00:01 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

foo_test.dart imports foo.dart as a package (not relative path).

```
import 'package:foo/foo.dart'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused due to me renaming the package name in `pubspec.yaml`.

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: foo_bar # <---- this was renamed from 'foo' to 'foo_bar'
description: An example dart project
version: 1.0.0

...
```

Any changes to pubspec.yaml requires running `flutter pub get` for the changes to take effect - including changing the package name, version, etc.